# Switching to design from source in .aspx page not working in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I don’t know well the reason behind it, it was working perfectly days ago and starts showing this issue these days. Fine, I’m using visual studio 2015 community, installed in windows 7 service pack 1. Please provide solutions to solve this issue as soon as possible. Note: Screen shots attached and kindly don’t suggest me to reinstall the entire application again.[image]

Comment: try to re-set your visual studio setting and re-start then try

Comment: @SunilKumar No changes occurred and having same problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to solve the issue is repair the application. For me it took half hour to complete the process and now its works good. Thanks for your help and support.

---